# proxy_pass to specified server port and directory

Tags: nginx

I want `mysite.com/*` to display content from `127.0.0.1:8080/dir/*`.

What I have that is currently 1:1 `mysite.com/*` to `127.0.0.1:8080/*`.

`sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

I tried several incantations to no avail. From here, I'm not sure whether to try setting `root`, using `rewrite`, messing with `proxy_pass`, use something other than `proxy_pass`, or something entirely. I just want to shoehorn a directory into my `proxy_pass` server and it is turning out to be more difficult than expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just using an HTTP in `proxy_pass`?

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/dir/;
}
```